# Perl Library for Unity

Tags: unity, 12.10, launcher, perl

Is there a Perl Library for the Unity Launcher? Apparently there needs to be one to be able to write feedback to the launcher (Like Message Counts) but so far I haven't been able to find one. So I am wondering if its even possible to make it work. Here's the explanation.

I am using the KildClient Mud Client, which is written in Perl. So far so good right? Well, if I want to write a plugin to allow feedback to the Launcher, I'm going to need something that can use Perl. Right? Unless of course there's command-lines to be used for that (Which theoretically would make it even easier)...

KildClient is a MU Client, or Chat Client, and I want to have a message count added so I stop missing every messages while I'm checking videos on youtube or something. I've seen X-chat being able to do those messages when receiving an important message, so I would like to be possible to do the same via perl! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Glib::Object::Introspection](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Glib-Object-Introspection/lib/Glib/Object/Introspection.pm) module, and load the `Unity` package through it to get access to the API for launchers. For indicators, you'd want to use `Indicate` for example. You'll also want to fail gracefully when they aren't available.

Comment: I actually don't know that much about Perl, is there somewhere I could learn more about the module and packages? As in how to use them and such?